# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message Discord Js bot V13.3.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am doing a project for school and I have just realised that I was building in on discord js v12 but I need it to be on discord v13. I am trying to fix the issues in my code but there seem to be many changes happened in v13. One of the issues I am facing the most is `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`. What is happened to a `message` and `description` in v13? I have many commands to correct, just want to understand what is this issue and how to fix it in existing code. Thank you so much in advance!

So the code below is reaction-roles from a message that is send to a specific channel. User can react with an emoji, and this role will appear in their profile. This code worked in discord js v12 fine..

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'role',

    async run (client, message, args) {

        const channelID = '918785339055829012';

        const firstRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'first')
        const secondRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'second')
        const thirdRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'third')
        const forthRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'forth')

        const firstEmoji = '';
        const secondEmoji = '';
        const thirdEmoji = '';
        const forthEmoji = '';

       let rolesInfo = `
        React to **role** to make it yours:
        ${firstEmoji} - first
        ${secondEmoji} - second
        ${thirdEmoji} - third
        ${forthEmoji} - forth`

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('Reaction roles')
        .setDescription(rolesInfo)

        let msgEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed)
        
        msgEmbed.react(firstEmoji)
        msgEmbed.react(secondEmoji)
        msgEmbed.react(thirdEmoji)
        msgEmbed.react(forthEmoji)

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.client) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channelID) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === firstEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(firstRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === secondEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(secondRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === thirdEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(thirdRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === forthEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(forthRole)
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });

        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.client) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channelID) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === firstEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(firstRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === secondEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(secondRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === thirdEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(thirdRole)
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === forthEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(forthRole)
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send an embed within a message you need to pass it inside an array to the `embeds` property of the `<MessageOptions>` parameter of the `<TextChannel>.send` method, like so:

```js
<TextChannel>.send({
    embeds: [<MessageEmbed>],
});
```